# Joomla site stop working after install libmysql-ruby libmysqlclient-dev

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, ubuntu, joomla

Ruby on Rails and Joomla site hosting on same server. after install libmysql-ruby libmysqlclient-dev joomla site giving me 'Error displaying the error page: Application Instantiation Error' error..

i already check configuration.php in joomla which is correct ..

Rails site is up and running but Joomla !!!!!

any suggestion how can fix joomla site problem..

Comment: I assume that they are in different directories yes? For example the Joomla site is on a subdomain or something

Comment: joomla site on main domain with 80 port and Rails App is running on 9090 port..